# Install4j Invalid Thread Access with SWT

Tags: install4j

When creating an installer for an SWT application for MacOSX, using a 64bit JRE, we are getting an 
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException:

```
Invalid thread access that we can trace to a line:
Display display = new Display().  
The error occurs when the application is launched after installation.
```

The same program works fine in development and in any Windows installations created with `Install4j.`  Is there something different that needs to be done with a `Mac OSX installer`, aside from our making sure to include the proper SWT jar for the target platform?

Indeed, this seems to be localized to launching on MacOSX after installing with Install4j.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your launcher in install4j, go to the "Executable info" step and select the "Uses SWT or QT" check box. Then it should work.

---

Update: For Apple JREs, the above is sufficient, but for Oracle JREs, the VM parameter `-XstartOnFirstThread` has to be added. From install4j 5.1.9 on, this will be added automatically.

Comment: That is already checked, along with 'fail if an exception in teh main thread is thrown'.

Comment: Please try to add the VM parameter -XstartOnFirstThread to the launcher

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.